# DreamHost error when trying to add a domain: “You can't add that domain: you must add the parent domain"

Tags: domain-registration, dreamhost

I have hosting account on DreamHost  I want to add  my domain (which is registered outside Dreamhost) I have already changed nameservers.
my domain is "xxxx.edu.eg"  but  I have the following problem:
"You can't add that domain: you must add the parent domain edu.eg to your account before adding a subdomain to it."
How to solve it and thank you in advance

Comment: The best way to solve it is to contact Dreamhost support ;o)

Answer (score 1):

The message is actually helpful in telling you what you need to do. `xxxx.edu.eg` has a subdomain, and they want you to add the base domain, `edu.eg` firstly before you can add the subdomain. The answer is also listed in their [documentation here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215416227-How-do-I-add-a-domain-#:%7E:text=are%20described%20below.-,You%20must%20add%20the%20parent%20domain,not%20yet%20in%20the%20system.).

Comment: Presumably they don't own the `edu.eg` domain and it wouldn't be appropriate to add it to their account.   Even if they did, it looks like only one dreamhost customer would be able to do that.

Comment: You can't own a subdomain without owning the base domain, though. And per the documentation:

> If you see:
> 
> "You can't add that domain: you must add the parent domain example.com to your account before adding a subdomain to it." it means that the second-level domain is not yet in the system. A subdomain can only be created if its second-level domain is created first (example.com)—even if you don't plan on hosting the second-level domain here at DreamHost.`

Comment: In many cases you can own a third level domain without owning the second level domain. this appears to be a country code that has an EDU second level domain that only has sites available on the third level